# Azure Media Services (v3) - specific output asset container name

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

I have a program similar to [AMSV3Quickstarts](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet-quickstarts/blob/master/AMSV3Quickstarts/EncodeAndStreamFiles/Program.cs) example and I need to change the default name for container for the output asset in accordance with my program logic/contract. Is it possible to change the output asset container name somehow?

What I tried:

- [RTFM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/job-input-from-local-file-how-to#net-sample)
- Change the transform job name
- Change the locator name
- Change the output asset name

However, in my blob storage, it is still in `asset-{GUID}` format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the REST API for Create Asset you are able to set the container name:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/:subscriptionId/resourceGroups/:resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Media/mediaServices/:accountName/assets/:assetName?api-version={{api-version}}

{
  "properties": {
    "description": "A documentary showing the ascent of Mount Logan",
    "alternateId": "(Optional) some GUID",
    "storageAccountName": "(Optional) someStorageAccount",
    "container": "(Optional) custom container name if you want"
  }
}
```

When using the .NET SDK, the Asset model contains the same parameters:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.media.models.asset?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: Maybe additional question: is it possible to place an asset into virtual directory? The container name with "/" char is not accepted by the API and properties such an assetId, Id or name do not affect virtual directory. Thanks

Comment: unfortunately no... the Container is the security boundary for us. So we need the files in individual containers to control the publishing behavior

Comment: @johndeu So there is no chance to have assets in blob structure like `assets/asset-{GUID}/*`? Or maybe sth changed since then?

Comment: You can modify the container name using the "container" property above.  But we don't support the fake hierarchy that storage provides throughs slashes.  Reason being is that the security controls are at the container level for publishing the asset streaming locators. Each "Asset" needs to be in its own container.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your really quick answer! You are right, working like a charm. I really appreciate your answer.

For the future me (and others) this is the working code:

```
        private static async Task<Asset> CreateOutputAssetAsync(IAzureMediaServicesClient client, string resourceGroupName, string accountName, string assetName)
        {
            Asset asset = new Asset();
            asset.Container = "mycustomnameformycontainer";
            string outputAssetName = assetName;

            return await client.Assets.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, accountName, outputAssetName, asset);
        }
```